# React-native in which database of saved cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The other day I was interviewing and I was asked the question "In which database is the cache stored on a mobile device?" I didn't even know what to say. How would you answer this question?
P.S. I answered AsyncStorage, he ask which database he uses

Comment: You can check here - [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one because it's going to rely heavily on context and if you've implemented an actual cache or it's just localStorage.

I would answer something like:

"When storing cache data on the device I would use `AsyncStorage` which will use the native storage mechanism (SharedPreferences / UserDefaults) however this isn't secure and if I needed to secure data on the device I would look towards a third party library that implements Keychain storage"

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if by database they meant `a SQL database` then [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). Other databases are available too [Realm, PouchDb, Watermelon DB, Vasern, Firebase (as local database)](https://blog.codemagic.io/choosing-the-right-database-for-react-native-app/).

For simple key-value storage, there is the [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) (deprecated but replaced by similar community packages). Other solutions exist but are specific to other frameworks (for example [Expo SecureStorage](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)).

*I would have proceded to investigate what are the Interviewer requirements to understand which of the listed solutions suits better the problem.*